# Showing Stats on data with 2 Input Date Fields Apex 5.1.0.00.45, Windows

Tags: sql, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a table with 2 date fields and other columns. I have to be able to show stats on some of these columns between 2 dates that can be selected from a dropdown list.
All of this must be done in Apex. The client must be able to select a Start Date and an End date and then the count of for instance the number of Referrals between 01/SEP/17 and 30/SEP/17 must be shown.
The SQL code I used in Oracle to achieve this is:

select 
   'Total Referrals' as Details, 
    count(REFERRED) as Total 
  from PD_PATIENT_DETAILS where REFERRED = 'Yes'
    and EVENT_DATE BETWEEN to_date(:EVENT_DATE) AND to_date(:EVENT_DATE_END);

I am now struggling to get this build in Apex. I only started working with Apex when I was brought onto this project. Have never worked with this before and am currently the only one working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 seperate page items and make them datepicker fields (P1_EVENT_DATE and P1_EVENT_DATE_END)

Your SQL query could look like this:

```
select 
    Total Referrals as Details
,   count(REFERRED) as Total 
from 
    PD_PATIENT_DETAILS
where 
    REFERRED = 'Yes' 
and EVENT_DATE between :P1_EVENT_DATE and :P1_EVENT_DATE_END
```

Then you need to make an dynamic action (on change of one of the items, or make a go button) which submits the page or refreshes the report region (then you have to set the page items into the session state).

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqhXC.jpg)

Comment: Thanks. Going to try this as soon as possible and let you know if I got it right. Thanks again.

Comment: Now get:                                                                                                             Error starting at line : 1 in command -
declare
    Details varchar2(50);
    Total varchar (50);
    P1_EVENT_DATE date;
    P1_EVENT_DATE_END date;
  Begin
    select 
      'Total Referrals' as Details,
      count(REFERRED) as Total 
    into Total, Details
  from 
    PD_PATIENT_DETAILS
  where 
    REFERRED = 'Yes' 
    and EVENT_DATE between :P1_EVENT_DATE and :P1_EVENT_DATE_END;
  END;
  
Error report -
Missing defines

Comment: Changed it to:                                                                                                    declare
    Details varchar2(20);
    Total number(18);
  Begin
    select
      'Total Referrals' as Details,
      count(REFERRED) as  Total
    INTO :Details, :Totals
  from 
    PD_PATIENT_DETAILS
  where 
    REFERRED = 'Yes' 
    and EVENT_DATE between :P1_EVENT_DATE and :P1_EVENT_DATE_END;
  END;  Get this in Apex now: Ajax call returned server error ORA-20876: Stop APEX Engine for Execute PL/SQL Code.